# How, Why and where is the table ci_sessions used in Codeigniter sessions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am really having a hard time to understand the use of the table ci_sessions. So I'm learning sessions and how to work with them in codeigniter and was introduced to this concept of creating a table in the below format,

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_sessions` (
  `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `data` blob NOT NULL
)
```

I have configured my CI application to work with the session library and I have even tried a simplate example like `$this->session->name = "Alex";` in which I observed that a new entry was created in the table. Everything is understandable up to this point but I cant understand potential places/places where I would use this table and what purpose it serves.

As an example Say I am supposed to use a session to "remember" a user who has logged in and for that I can use something like the below,

`$this->session->isLoggedIn = True;` and pass this through places where I want to skip the authentication. What is the use of this table and out of the data in it what can I do from it.

Would really appreciate of someone can clear this for me.

I did try my best and came across this question but it was not marked as answered : [How to use session table in code igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717777/how-to-use-session-table-in-code-igniter)